# inefficient recursive code to produce Fibonacci number in java

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci

The following recursive method is intended to produce a Fibonacci number for a given integer (written in Java)

```
   public static long fib(int n)
   {
      if (n == 0)
         return (long)0;
      else if (n == 1)
         return (long)1;
      else
         return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
   }
```

But what I found is that it was taking more than 20 seconds to produce a Fibonacci number at the position of 48th or higher. Can you help to explain why this Fib producer is so inefficient?

For example, here I attach a simple testing client:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       int hi = 50;

       System.out.println("Sequance, elapsed time, number");

       for (int n = 0; n<= hi; n++)
       {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long fib_num = fib(n);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long elapse = (end-start)/1000;  
            System.out.printf("%d, %d, %d%n", n, elapse, fib_num);
       }
   }
```

and its output is (running on a i7, 4core MacBook Pro 2017 model):

```
Sequance, elapsed time, number
0, 0, 0
1, 0, 1
2, 0, 1
3, 0, 2
4, 0, 3
5, 0, 5
6, 0, 8
7, 0, 13
8, 0, 21
9, 0, 34
10, 0, 55
11, 0, 89
12, 0, 144
13, 0, 233
14, 0, 377
15, 0, 610
16, 0, 987
17, 0, 1597
18, 0, 2584
19, 0, 4181
20, 0, 6765
21, 0, 10946
22, 0, 17711
23, 0, 28657
24, 0, 46368
25, 0, 75025
26, 0, 121393
27, 0, 196418
28, 0, 317811
29, 0, 514229
30, 0, 832040
31, 0, 1346269
32, 0, 2178309
33, 0, 3524578
34, 0, 5702887
35, 0, 9227465
36, 0, 14930352
37, 0, 24157817
38, 0, 39088169
39, 0, 63245986
40, 0, 102334155
41, 0, 165580141
42, 1, 267914296
43, 2, 433494437
44, 3, 701408733
45, 5, 1134903170
46, 8, 1836311903
47, 14, 2971215073
48, 22, 4807526976
49, 34, 7778742049
50, 58, 12586269025
```

Comment: Because recursive Fibonacci *is* inefficient. Do some analysis, say on *fib(8)*, and see exactly why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is primarily because of the fact that this implementation of generating Fibonacci numbers is extremely inefficient.

This particular algorithm grows exponentially instead of linearly because each call of Fibonacci branches off into two more calls and continues on this track. Thus, increasing the size of N heavily increases the time required to complete.

A better approach would be keep track of the previous values for computing the next value.

```
long fibbonaci(int n) {
    long c = 0, k = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        k += c;
        c = k - c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*This is a classical problem of recursion where Dynamic programming comes into rescue .*

What actually happens is that your code do some recalculations which are already being done, hence result in extra machine cycle and high processing time.

[image]

Above picture depicts how your program calculates 5th Fibonacci Number .
We can see that the function f(3) is being called 2 times fib(2) 3 times fib(1) 5 times, instead of calculating it for one time.

## **Solution**

If we would have stored the value of f(3),f(2),f(1) then instead of computing it again, we could have reused the old stored value.
From here you can do the research and can have a read from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example where you should be using memoization. You need to memoize already calculated numbers. In simple words, you need to maintain a data structure which can be an array in this case which will hold the fibonacci number for that index.

Sample array will look like this(Starting from index 0)

> 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13

So, whenever you need to calculate a fibonacci number, first check in the array if a fibonacci number has already been calculated. If yes, then return it from the array. If not, then calculate it and store it in the array.

Comment: How much time do you spend searching the array at each step? Do you really need to remember *all* the previous numbers or just the last two?

Comment: Time spent in accessing the array element is O(1) as it's index will be used and will not be searched through the whole array. Maintaining only last 2 will work and you will save on space.

Comment: Ah, right…I was imagining you looking for `13` in the array (which of course is dumb) rather than `array[n-1]`.